# How to store images directly in SqliteStudio in android without storing it from the app

Tags: android, database

I wanted to start my project for a bilingual terminology app and for the noun terms I wanted to store images in the sqlite database and display whenever the user clicks the term. I know how to add the images in database using the app but I don't have any idea how to store it directly in database using SqliteStudio.users do not have the option to store image in database but just to retrieve to when the option is clicked.

Comment: To be clear: you are looking for a non-programmatical way of adding image blob data to a schema?

Comment: not really a non-programmatical but to store the images in the internal file and to store just the path of the image in database.users do not have the privilege to store but just to retrieve the images.

Comment: You'll want to make that clear in the question with an [edit], not in comments.  But, unless you can show that this question is primarily about code, it's going to be hard for you to get any traction here. Ref: [ask]